# Problems with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have problems with my app. In 1 thread it works good, but when I change thread > 1
it doesn't work right.

I have 3 lists:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>();
List<string> passwords = new List<string>();
    struct Proxy
    {
        public static List<string> proxies = new List<string>();
        public static string type;
    }
```

And I need that all threads take first url, all threads take first proxy, each thread takes unik(next) password from list. If first 5 threads take 5 passwords, proxy changes to next and these threads take next 5 unique passes.
How to solve this?

```
    Thread[] thr;
    static object locker = new object();
    int good_auth, bad_auth, j;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal value = numericUpDown2.Value;
        int i = 0;
        int k = (int)(value);
        thr = new Thread[k];
        for (; i < k; i++)
        {
            thr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));
            thr[i].IsBackground = true;
            thr[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void go()
    {
        string urlANDlogin = "";
        for (int url_index = 0; url_index < urls.Count; url_index++)
        {
            urlANDlogin = urls[url_index];
            string proxy = "";
            string password = "";

            if (Proxy.proxies.Count != 0)
            {
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    Proxy.type = "http";
                else if (checkBox2.Checked)
                    Proxy.type = "socks5";
                else
                    Proxy.type = "none";
            }


            VB vb = new VB(urlANDlogin, Proxy.type);
            for (int proxy_index = 0; proxy_index < Proxy.proxies.Count; proxy_index++)
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    if (Proxy.proxies.Count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        proxy = Proxy.proxies[proxy_index];
                }
                vb.Proxy(proxy);
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        if (passwords.Count == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            password = passwords[j];
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    string login = vb.Auth(password);
                    if (login == "Good")
                    {
                        lock (locker)
                        {
                            good_auth++;
                            log_good(good_auth);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lock (locker)
                        {
                            bad_auth++;
                            log_bad(bad_auth);
                        }
                    }                            

                }
                lock (locker)
                {
                    log_left_proxy(Proxy.proxies.Count);
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what "it don't work right" means.

Comment: each thread takes non-unique password

Comment: unless I am missing something, your threads are all accessing the same lists, unsynchronized, and starting at index zero ( for loop )

Comment: Also, you are accessing lists inside of lists which keeps you from accessing them independently, so you will need one giant mutex for the entire method rather then at the list level.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Data Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx) from TPL.

Something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(urls, url => Process(url));
```

Besides all the other comments, you cannot access a Control from a non-UI thread.  So you must get the values of `checkBox1` and `checkBox2` in your click method.